# Leaflet decorator throw this error "Error: Invalid LatLng object: (NaN, NaN)"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, leaflet

i am able to draw the polyline on the map . But after that when ever i call polyline decorator it is crashing . Here is my code

```
var polyline = new L.Polyline(L.PolylineUtil.decode(updatedPolyLine, 6)).addTo(mapDisplay);
var decorator = new L.polylineDecorator(polyline, {
      patterns: [
          // defines a pattern of 10px-wide dashes, repeated every 20px on the line
          {offset: 0, repeat: 20, symbol: L.Symbol.dash({pixelSize: 10})}
      ]
}).addTo(mapDisplay);
```

Here is the error

```
Error: Invalid LatLng object: (NaN, NaN)
    at new o.LatLng (http://localhost:30080/bower_components/leaflet/dist/leaflet.js:6:13842)
    at Object.unproject (http://localhost:30080/bower_components/leaflet/dist/leaflet.js:6:17613)
    at Object.pointToLatLng (http://localhost:30080/bower_components/leaflet/dist/leaflet.js:6:17998)
    at e.unproject (http://localhost:30080/bower_components/leaflet/dist/leaflet.js:6:24596)
    at http://localhost:30080/bower_components/leaflet-polylinedecorator/dist/leaflet.polylineDecorator.js:45:25
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at projectPatternOnPath (http://localhost:30080/bower_components/leaflet-polylinedecorator/dist/leaflet.polylineDecorator.js:43:61)
    at e._getDirectionPoints (http://localhost:30080/bower_components/leaflet-polylinedecorator/dist/leaflet.polylineDecorator.js:438:16)
    at http://localhost:30080/bower_components/leaflet-polylinedecorator/dist/leaflet.polylineDecorator.js:462:38
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at e._getPatternLayers (http://localhost:30080/bower_components/leaflet-polylinedecorator/dist/leaflet.polylineDecorator.js:461:28)
    at http://localhost:30080/bower_components/leaflet-polylinedecorator/dist/leaflet.polylineDecorator.js:479:27
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at e._draw (http://localhost:30080/bower_components/leaflet-polylinedecorator/dist/leaflet.polylineDecorator.js:478:24)
    at e.onAdd (http://localhost:30080/bower_components/leaflet-polylinedecorator/dist/leaflet.polylineDecorator.js:406:14)
    at e._layerAdd (http://localhost:30080/bower_components/leaflet/dist/leaflet.js:6:29891)
    at e.addLayer (http://localhost:30080/bower_components/leaflet/dist/leaflet.js:6:21393)
    at e.addTo (http://localhost:30080/bower_components/leaflet/dist/leaflet.js:7:25630)
    at Object.fn (http://localhost:30080/scripts/controllers/kocotrack.js:600:24)
    at Scope.$digest (http://localhost:30080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12650:29)
    at Scope.$apply (http://localhost:30080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12915:24)
    at done (http://localhost:30080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8450:45)
    at completeRequest (http://localhost:30080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8664:7)
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (http://localhost:30080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8603:11)
    at XMLHttpRequest.d (http://localhost:30080/bower_components/raven-js/dist/raven.min.js:2:4340) undefined
```

Here is a copy paste of console.log of polyline

```
 e {options: {…}, _latlngs: Array(258), _initHooksCalled: true, editing: e, _leaflet_events: {…}}
editing: e {_poly: e, options: {…}, _initHooksCalled: true}
options: {stroke: true, color: "#0033ff", dashArray: null, lineCap: null, lineJoin: null, …}
_container: g
_initHooksCalled: true
_latlngs: (258) [o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, o.LatLng, …]
_leaflet_events: {add: Array(1), remove: Array(1)}
_leaflet_id: 135
_map: e {options: {…}, _container: div#overview.angular-leaflet-map.ng-isolate-scope.leaflet-container.leaflet-retina.leaflet-fade-anim, _panes: {…}, _mapPane: div.leaflet-map-pane, _tilePane: div.leaflet-tile-pane, …}
_originalPoints: (258) [o.Point, ...
```

Comment: ...and what's the value of the `polyline` variable at runtime just before the error is thrown?

Comment: Hi @IvanSanchez i updated the question here is a console.log at the polyline

Comment: Leaflet Polyline Decorator plugin might have troubles with your particular polyline. You should provide a data sample that reproduces the issue. Ideally a live reproduction example, that would greatly help people understanding your issue.